# What is the most efficient way to get pairs' array from two same sized arrays

Tags: kdb

In case if there are two arrays of the same size, like

```
array1: 1 2 3 4 5;
array2: 6 7 8 9 10;
```

What is the most efficient way to form the next array:

```
((1 6); (2 7); (3 8); (4 9); (5 10))
```

Answer (score 4):

`q)array1: 1 2 3 4 5;
q)array2: 6 7 8 9 10;
q)array1,'array2
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10`

Comment: No problem. I advise going through the free kdb guides we provide (http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/) and those on code/kx . It will give you the kdb fundamentals. Then move onto your own small projects.

Answer (score 3):

Could also

```
flip (array1;array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass each element of `array1` & `array2` to a function directly then `each-both` can be used :

```
q)array1: 1 2 3 4 5;
q)array2: 6 7 8 9 10;
q)f:{x,y}
q)f'[array1;array2]
(1j, 6j;2j, 7j;3j, 8j;4j, 9j;5j, 10j)
```